# animategraphics is off center in beamer (using animate package)

Tags: beamer, animate

I'm trying to use the animate package, but when I insert an animation into beamer using the `animategraphics` command, the result is horribly off-center.   This occurs even if I use `\begin{center}\end{center}` commands.

Here's some stripped-down code to illustrate the problem.  I used colors so that the off-centeredness is clearly visible.

Here's the "master" file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}[16:9]
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\begin{frame}
\animategraphics[]{1}{animate-test-frames}{0}{0}
\end{frame}
} % end setbeamercolor
\end{document}
```

And here's the `animate-test-frames.tex` file to go with it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}[16:9]
\begin{document}
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
} % end setbeamercolor
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

It seems like there should be a simple way to fix this.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your graphic is too large. You should either scale it or set the margins to zero.

Answer (score 1):

A similar result would be obtained with `\includegraphics[page=1]{animate-test-frames}`. The PDF with animation frames is too wide to be inserted as normal slide content.

Use a combination of `\usebackgroundtemplate{...}` and an empty plain `\frame{}` that is put in a group (`{`...`}`) in order to insert a *slide-filling* animation. The `plain` option should be set in case the presentation makes use of a theme, as in this example:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{First frame}
\end{frame}

{
\usebackgroundtemplate{\animategraphics[autoplay]{1}{animate-test-frames}{}{}}
\frame[plain]{}
}% end of \usebackgroundtemplate

\begin{frame}{Last frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that the correct way for setting a 16:9 aspect ratio for `beamer` is `aspectratio=169`, put as document class option. Thus, the animation frames are made with this code:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\begin{document}
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
} % end setbeamercolor
\end{document}
```